# Git Hook: How to tell if tagged commit has been merged to master

Tags: git, git-post-receive

I'm trying to write git hooks to deploy a web app on push.

I have cloned a bare repo from origin and written a pre-receive hook to enforce certain rules.
One of the rules is that only annotated tags should be deployed and that all changes must have been merged into master.

In order to enforce the second rule, I am trying to use post-receive and to a

```
  git branch --contains <tag_name>
```

in order to see whether master is in the list.

When I do this on origin, I get

```
  master
* testbranch
```

but when I run the same command in the bare repo on the deployment server, I only get

```
* (detached from e5f1fa4)
```

Am I missing something or does this approach simply not work on a bare repo?

If that is the case, is there any other way to verify that a tag's commit has been merged into master already?

Comment: use `git merge-base --is-ancestor` instead

Comment: That actually works well and has the added benefit of providing the result by way of exit status.

Answer (score 0):

First, do `git show <tag_name>` and copy the hash of that commit.

Then, just grep `git log` for that hash:

```
git log master | grep <hash>
```

If no output is returned, then the hash has not been merged to the master branch.  Otherwise, the hash will be output from grep, indicating that it has been merged.

To do it all in a single command:

```
git log master | grep "`git show <tag_name> | grep commit`"
```